# Constraint on Column Based on Another Column Value

Tags: sql, database, oracle, function, constraints

I'm writing a sql constraint about values on columns based on some conditions in Oracle database. My table is like below.(assume **id** is auto increment, also 'alpha' and 'beta' columns are numbers)

```
   id    alpha    beta
--------------------------
   1      1        0
   2      1        1
   3      0        0
   4      0        0
   5      2        3
   6      4        1
```

If alpha  value in two rows are same, only one row can be inserted with beta value of 1. In other words, i shouldn't insert a row with **(1,1)** values because there is already a row  with beta value of **1**.(look at the row with id=2). Any value besides **1** can be inserted freely. I need a useful control about that situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use unique index with condition-based column as follows:

```
create unique index u123
on your_table (alpha, case when beta = 1 then beta else id end)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, it's working. What if i write "when beta =1 then -1" like Gordon's answer. Would that affect my outcome in near or future?

Comment: You should use id as it is PK and will be different for each row so it can better serve your purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a function-based index:

```
create unique index xxx on t(a, case when b = 1 then -1 else id end)
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1693af043678616160ffc46c5aa4b958) is a db<>fiddle.